# How to calculate time complexity with no code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have to demonstrate that (`^` is raising into power):

1. `n^2 = O(2^n)`
2. `n^2 = Θ(2^n)`
3. `8^n = O(4^n)`
4. `8^n = Ω(4^n)`

Is there a *theoretic* method that always works to know if it’s **true** or **false**, and give the demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

These are *limit computation* problems:

```
f(n) = O(g(n))   if and only if      lim (f(n)/g(n)) = 0
                                       n -> +inf

f(n) = Θ(g(n))   if and only if      lim (f(n)/g(n)) = some positive finite number
                                       n -> +inf 

f(n) = Ω(g(n))   if and only if      lim (f(n)/g(n)) = +inifinity
                                       n -> +inf
```

Or, put it reversed

```
Let x = lim(f(n)/g(n))
          n -> +inf

x = 0 ?                          then f(n) = O(g(n))
x = some postive finite number ? then f(n) = Θ(g(n)) 
x = +infinity ?                  then f(n) = Ω(g(n))
```

So, we have to compute limits, e.g. in the 1st case:

```
 lim(n^2/2^n) = 0 (apply l'Hospital's rule twice)
   n -> +inf
```

that's why `n^2 = O(2^n)` etc:

```
 n^2 = O(2^n)  - true
 n^2 = Θ(2^n)  - false, in fact O(2^n)
 8^n = O(4^n)  - false, in fact Ω(2^n) 
 8^n = Ω(4^n)  - true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [the definition of each of the terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) and work from them.

---

Let's take 1. We need *k* and *n<sub>0</sub>* such that

|*n*<sup>2</sup>| ≤ *k*·2<sup>*n*</sup> for *n* > *n*<sub>0</sub>

For example, *k* = 1 and *n*<sub>0</sub> = 3 work in this case. For *n* = 4, we would have 16 ≤ 16, which is good. Now we can reason by induction. Assume it works for *n*, see if it does for *n* + 1. We would have

|(*n* + 1)<sup>2</sup>| ≤ *k*·2<sup>(*n* + 1)</sup>

We know everything is positive, so we can remove the absolute value, and we can operate like:

*n*<sup>2</sup> + 2·n + 1 ≤ *k*·2<sup>(*n* + 1)</sup> → *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 + n + 1/2 ≤ *k*·2<sup>*n*</sup>

Now we knew that *k*·2<sup>*n*</sup> ≥ *n*<sup>2</sup> (induction hypothesis), so it suffices to demonstrate

*n*<sup>2</sup>/2 + n + 1/2 ≤ *n*<sup>2</sup> → 1/2 + 1/*n* + 1/(2·n<sup>2</sup>) ≤ 1

Some more operations and you reach:

n<sup>2</sup> - 2·n - 1 ≥ 0 → (n - 1)<sup>2</sup> - 2 ≥ 0

Which is trivially true for *n* > *n*<sub>0</sub> = 3

---

Let's take now 3 as negative example. This one is false, 8<sup>*n*</sup> ≠ *O*(4<sup>*n*</sup>). Suppose there exist valid *k* and *n*<sub>0</sub> values for this one. Then *i* steps later, you should have

|8<sup>*n*<sub>0</sub> + *i*</sup>| ≤ *k*·4<sup>*n*<sub>0</sub> + *i*</sup>

so

*k*·4<sup>*n*<sub>0</sub> + i</sup> / |8<sup>*n*<sub>0</sub> + *i*</sup>| ≥ 1

Since *n*<sub>0</sub> and *i* are positive you can rewrite as:

*k*·(4/8)<sup>*n*<sub>0</sub> + *i*</sup> ≥ 1

But obviously the limit of the left-hand side of the inequation for *i* → ∞ is 0 so *k* and *n*<sub>0</sub> cannot be valid values.

---

You should be able reason similarly for the rest. For 2., Theta involves two inequalities, you have to either demonstrate both or refute one; in this case it is false, 2<sup>*n*</sup> is not a lower bound of *n*<sup>2</sup>. For 4., should be along the lines of 1. (this one is true), but reversing the sign of the inequality.